# ParseUser class "User" is not being updated . How to update "User" class?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have the default ParseUser class "User". The problem is that when I am trying to insert data into a new column in that class "updatePOST" using querying but it does not update.

That column shows "undefined". Plus I want that column "updatePOST" to hold only the latest string. I have also tried giving manually the objectId but noting happens.

Here is the code

```
public class ChangeAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_account);


        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_pic_change);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.changeUpdatePost);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                String objectId = currentUser.getObjectId();
                final String updatePost = editText.getText().toString();
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                query.getInBackground((String) objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                        if(e == null){
                            parseObject.put("updatePOST",updatePost);
                            parseObject.saveInBackground();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Intent i = new Intent(ChangeAccount.this,Account.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have created a new "Update" class. And have put data in it. Also the above query is working fine for that class. The values are updating. So basically only the problem is with the default User class.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the Installation object. Can you try adding the column into the User table in the parse dashboard? Creating that new data column along with the right data type worked for me.

**Update 5/4/16 **

Once you get the current ParseUser from ParseUser.getCurrentUser() you can immediately put key/value pairs on ParseUser. You don't need to construct another ParseQuery to get the User object. Please see the [put](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) method in the reference docs. Once you've set the desired key/value pair, you can then call saveInBackground() right away.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. I created the column "updatePOST" with type "string" beforehand. But nothing happens. It does not update anything and shows "undefined".

Comment: Are you certain that the ParseQuery returns successfully and that ParseException is null? I would try adding Log statements above and printing out the toString of the ParseObject.

Comment: As you said, ParseException is not null , showing exception. What to do ?

Comment: Exception is "no results found for query"

Comment: Now I have created a new Class "Update" and put some data in it. But the above query is working and the value is updating. SO basically I am unable to update the Default User class.

Comment: Please see the updated answer Abhishek. You actually need to create another data table "Update" to do what you want. The ParseUser itself can be used to set the updatePost column on the User table.